# Why is my dart script is getting so slow?

Tags: dart

I am trying to add new data to keys named "translations" in my items for all files sitting in the Directory.
However, as soon as I enable the commented section in the method `translateRecipeMatching` and want to merge my recipes, my script gets so slow/wonky that a simple `log(recipeMatchingList.length.toString())` in that method crashes my visual studio code window and I have to restart it. Without that block the script ends in around 10 seconds but with that block I can wait over 5 minutes and nothing will happen.

Every other section runs in a reasonable time bewteen 1 and 5 seconds, for reference

Why is my script becoming so slow?

The translations list has around 23434 Elements and recipeMatchingList has 1419 elements. Recipelist contains around 700 elements.

The script is this:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:translationMatcherNorviah/languagemaps.dart';
import 'package:translationMatcherNorviah/sourcepaths.dart';

enum Mergemode { normal, recipes }

List<Map<String, dynamic>> translationList = [];

List<String> clothingCategorys = [
  "Accessories",
  "Bags",
  "Bottoms",
  "Dress-Up",
  "Headwear",
  "Shoes",
  "Socks",
  "Tops",
  "Clothing Other"
];

void setJsonFileAsString(Mergemode mergemode) {
  List<String> jsonPaths = getJsonDataPaths(mergemode);

  //Read translations
  if (translationList.isEmpty) {
    List<dynamic> translationData =
        json.decode(File("json/sources/translations/translationsNew.json").readAsStringSync());

    for (int j = 0; j < translationData.length; j++) {
      Map<String, dynamic> tempMap = translationData[j];
      translationList.add(tempMap);
    }
  }

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> recipeMatchingList = [];

  if (mergemode == Mergemode.recipes) {
    //Read recipeMatchingList
    recipeMatchingList = loadRecipeClothMatchingList();
  }

  //Loop through all files in the path List
  for (int i = 0; i < jsonPaths.length; i++) {
    String currentPath = jsonPaths[i];

    print("Extracting from Filepath: ${jsonPaths[i]}");

    //open the json file
    List<dynamic> data = json.decode(File(currentPath).readAsStringSync());

    List<Map<String, dynamic>> categoryItemList = [];

    //Make sure that the dynamic type gets converted into a Map
    //Doing it not this way causes an exception
    for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
      Map<String, dynamic> tempMap = data[j];
      categoryItemList.add(tempMap);
    }

    List<Map<String, dynamic>> outPutList = [];

    //Merge in translations depending on the files propertys
    for (int j = 0; j < categoryItemList.length; j++) {
      outPutList.add(
        addTranslationsToItem(categoryItemList[j], recipeMatchingList),
      );
    }

    //Create a new file at the output path
    print("Writing to File: json/output/${getFileName(currentPath)}");
    File newFile = File("json/output/${getFileName(currentPath)}");

    //Write data to the new File
    newFile.createSync();
    newFile.writeAsStringSync(json.encode(categoryItemList));
  }
}

String getFileName(String filePath) {
  String fileName = "";

  fileName = filePath.split("/").last;

  return fileName;
}

Map<String, dynamic> addTranslationsToItem(Map<String, dynamic> item, List<Map<String, dynamic>> recipeMatchingList) {
  Map<String, dynamic> translation = {};

  bool hasVariants = item.containsKey("variations");
  bool clothGroupMatching = (clothingCategorys.contains(item["sourceSheet"]));
  bool fileNameMatching = (item["sourceSheet"] == "Sheet1");
  bool iconFileNameMatching = (item["sourceSheet"] == "Sheet2");
  bool recipeMatching = (item["sourceSheet"] == "Recipes");
  bool hasPlural = (item["sourceSheet"] == "Other");

  //The method will loop through the list of translations once and collect the nessecary translations for the item
  for (int i = 0; i < translationList.length; i++) {
    translation = translationList[i];

    //See if the item does not have any specific category and add the translations in the fitting style
    if (!clothGroupMatching && !recipeMatching && !fileNameMatching && !iconFileNameMatching && !hasPlural) {
      item = translateMatchInternalId(item, translation);
    }

    //See if the item a Recipe and add the translations in the fitting style
    if (!clothGroupMatching && recipeMatching && !fileNameMatching && !iconFileNameMatching && !hasPlural) {
      item = translateRecipeMatching(item, translation, recipeMatchingList);
    }
  }

  return item;
}

Map<String, dynamic> translateMatchInternalId(Map<String, dynamic> item, Map<String, dynamic> translation) {
  bool hasVariants = item.containsKey("variations");
  String itemInternalId = hasVariants ? item["variations"][0]["internalId"].toString() : item["internalId"].toString();

  if (translation["id"].toString() == itemInternalId) {
    Map<String, dynamic> tempMap = {};
    translation.forEach((key, value) {
      String oldLanguageString = getOldLanguageString(key);
      tempMap[oldLanguageString] = value;
    });

    item["translations"] = tempMap;
  }

  return item;
}

Map<String, dynamic> translateMatchFileName(Map<String, dynamic> item, Map<String, dynamic> translation) {
  String itemFileName = item["filename"];

  if (translation["id"].toString() == itemFileName) {
    Map<String, dynamic> tempMap = {};
    translation.forEach((key, value) {
      String oldLanguageString = getOldLanguageString(key);
      tempMap[oldLanguageString] = value;
    });

    item["translations"] = tempMap;
  }

  return item;
}


Map<String, dynamic> translateRecipeMatching(
    Map<String, dynamic> item, Map<String, dynamic> translation, List<Map<String, dynamic>> recipeMatchingList) {
  //First we need to find out if the item is a cloth type and needs GroupID Matching or Internal ID Matching
  bool needsGroupIdMatching = item["category"] == "Equipment";
  String craftedItemId = item["craftedItemInternalId"].toString();

  if (needsGroupIdMatching) {
    for (int k = 0; k < recipeMatchingList.length; k++) {
      Map<String, dynamic> matchingListItem = recipeMatchingList[k];
      bool matchingItemHasVariations = matchingListItem.containsKey("variations");

      String matchingListItemId = "";

      if (matchingItemHasVariations) {
        matchingListItemId = matchingListItem["variations"][0]["internalId"].toString();
      } else {
        matchingListItemId = matchingListItem["internalId"].toString();
      }

      if (craftedItemId == matchingListItemId) {
        if (matchingItemHasVariations) {
          craftedItemId = matchingListItem["variations"][0]["clothGroupId"].toString();
        } else {
          matchingListItemId = matchingListItem["clothGroupId"].toString();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  //We need to load the target item files:

  if (translation["id"].toString() == craftedItemId) {
    Map<String, dynamic> tempMap = {};
    translation.forEach((key, value) {
      String oldLanguageString = getOldLanguageString(key);
      tempMap[oldLanguageString] = value;
    });

    item["translations"] = tempMap;
  }

  return item;
}

List<Map<String, dynamic>> loadRecipeClothMatchingList() {
  List<dynamic> clothingData = [];

  for (int i = 0; i < jsonDataPaths.length; i++) {
    String filename = getFileName(jsonDataPaths[i]);
    if (clothingFiles.containsValue(filename)) {
      clothingData.addAll(json.decode(File(jsonDataPaths[i]).readAsStringSync()));
    }
  }

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> clothingDataMapList = [];

  for (int j = 0; j < clothingData.length; j++) {
    Map<String, dynamic> tempMap = clothingData[j];
    clothingDataMapList.add(tempMap);
  }

  print("Clothmatchinglist length is: " + clothingDataMapList.length.toString());

  return clothingDataMapList;
}
```

Comment: Can you upload a project to github which reproduces your problem and which we can run? Your posted example are missing multiple parts before it is possible to run it. I have a suspicion your problem is that your are creating a very large Object model and then wants to serialize it to JSON in one go. Since Dart does not have a builtin  streaming way to convert an object to JSON, this process will end up taking a lot of memory and CPU resources. But it is just a guess and there can be lot of other reasons in your long complicated program. Therefore I really wanted to test the program for myself.

Comment: I think that you got the right hunch. I cleaned everthing up and it starts failing as soon as I add the additional List of maps I want to use to combine everything. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to make exactly but would a possible solution be to use sqlite or some other database which is actually made for handling a bunch of data? It does not really seem that JSON is the fitting format for what you are trying to make. But again, I don't know anything about your program. :)